# Virtual Machine in RHEL6

Tags: networking, virtualization, redhat, virtual-machines

Can we configure virtualization or make virtual machines which have access from and to other outer n/w's using GUI?

Because I tried making VMs using command mode, and it didn't work out. So is there anyway I can configure graphically with minimum command mode?

And I am a beginner of Networking Concepts, so I hope you will give a wide expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question - yes, it's possible.

In order to receive detailed answers though, you'd have to provide more details on what you want to achieve and how, and what you have already done so far

Comment: Make 4 Virtual machines with static IP's
192.168.125.22
192.168.125.23
192.168.125.24
192.168.125.25

Through Host Machine with Static IP
192.168.125.19

Using Bridge,bridge0

And Accessible by N/W from 192.168.1.*

Can i get a general idea,How this is possible in RHEL6 with KVM.

The Problem is

i made VM's with Static IP,
But i couldnt access to other N/W from this VM and not access from other N/W this VM's.

Comment: I really dont understand where i messed it.Bcoz i was using more of command mode operations.I want to start from beginning with GUI.So is there a possibility of creating this with more GUI and less Commands.

Comment: Thanks dyasny for the response, and please try to help me out.

Comment: make sure you have a working network, with a bridge built on top of the NIC, using the bridge for networking instead of the NIC itself. Once you have that, all you need to do it set the networking mode of the VMs to "bridged", and attach them to the bridge as well. This will make the bridge also operate as a virtual hub for the VMs

Comment: I did understand what you said and to my surprise the vm's are working now.